# Write Textbox.text to dataset then to xml file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I found several examples on how to write to dataset, but most of them involve a ds.fill(..) from a data connection and I need a simpler solution. Basically I want to create an xml file from the values entered in a few textbox. I tried different methods but can't make it work.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

One method I used was to fill the textboxes from an xml, but now how do I write it back to the xml once the user has changed the data in the textbox?

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.ReadXml("c:\sales.xml")
    CashTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "Cash")
    CheckTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "Check")
    VisaTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "Visa")
    MasterCardTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "Mastercard")
    AMEXTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "AMEX")
    NovusTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "Novus")
    TottransTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "Tottrans") End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the intent here is, but one way you could do this is:

Create a DataSet
Add a DataTable
Add DataRows with your relevant information from each text box as a DataRow for each relevant text box.
Call [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) on the DataSet

**EDIT:** Here is an example thrown together based on your comment, it's simplistic, I've iterated through a loop instead of all textboxes: http://www.pastie.org/806266. You might want to update your question in terms of what your overall goal is, looping through text boxes to stuff things in a data set and then call write WriteXml is pretty old school, 3.5 makes constructing XML much easier, can you elaborate on what your long term goal is.

Comment: by any chance you have an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Can't you just use **[ds.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx)**

Comment: Looks like I didn't ask correctly... = )

In the code above I am using the Load event of the form to fill the text boxes. When I am trying to add the ds.writeXML to the buttonclick event it's telling me that ds is not defined.

I just need an example of how to write the user inputs from the textbox.text once modified.